# Desde hace un tiempo no me funciona bien el local host de xampp

Tags: xampp

Desde hace un tiempo, cuando cambio algo de un archivo y actualizo la página, es como si no lo cambiará, inspeccionó el código y lo que yo cambie no ha cambiado en la web, a veces al recargar varias veces se arregla, pero luego vuelve, también me pasa que alomejor un archivo si se recarga pero otros no y se me esta haciendo difícil programar así ya que a veces nose si no se cambio lo que cambie y tengo que estar revisando todo elr ato si se actualizo y esperar a que se actualize

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

podrias probar con cambiar de puerto de xampp, no se cual estes usando pero el 8080 lo podrias probar.
y si el problema persiste que te parece usar Wamp.

la idea es la misma y funciona de la misma manera

te dejo estos posts.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

https://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Buenas acabo de intentar lo del puerto y me sale error, cannot create file control.ini, acceso denegado, y me pasa con todo lo que intenté configurar

Comment: Pero muchas gracias igualmente, instalare wampserver haber